# Having trouble installing Azure SDK 2.9.1 on VS 15 Preview 4

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-sdk

When I try installing Azure SDK 2.9.1 for VS 15 Prev 4, I get the following error message:

> You must enable Visual Studio Web Development Feature in Visual Studio VS "15" Preview before you can install this product.

[image: Azure SDK 2.9.1 installation error]

I do have all boxes checked under "Web development" section in the installation options of VS 15 Prev 4.

[image: VS 15 Prev 4 installation options]

Looking for any ideas how to resolve or troubleshoot this issue.

**EDIT:**

Perhaps this is related to the fact that Azure tooling didn't make it to VS 15 Prev 4 according to this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/08/22/visual-studio-15-preview-4/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per: https://www.visualstudio.com/news/releasenotes/vs15-relnotes#knownissues

**Azure SDK for .Net cannot be installed with Visual Studio "15" Preview 4**

**Issue:**

If you try to install the Azure SDK for .Net from the Web Platform Installer, you will get an error saying that you need to install the Web Tools Extensions and the Azure SDK won't install.

**Workaround:**

The Azure SDK for .Net is supported on Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2015, and Visual Studio "15" Preview 3. Please use one of those versions to run the Azure SDK for .Net.